# Can I listen for Ctrl+C at the Psychopy console window?

Tags: exception, try-catch, console-application, psychopy, keyboardinterrupt

Will it register `KeyboardInterrupt` exception instead? The application logic assumes there will be at least one Psychopy window active at the time, but the keyboard commands can be input into the console window.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my code to capture control-C, an explanation of how/why it works, a trap to avoid in making it work with PsychoPy's `waitKeys()`, and a pointer to another helpful stackoverflow discussion, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71095679/2901493).